# Is TWRP available for Samsung Galaxy Note 1 (GT-N7000, GT-N7000B)? Otherwise, what recovery can I use?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, samsung-galaxy-note

I was browsing https://twrp.me/Devices/ wondering if TWRP is available for Samsung Galaxy Note 1 (GT-N7000, or GT-N7000B in my specific case).

Only the T-Mobile (quincytmo) and AT&T (quincyatt) versions are listed there, which seems strange to me as the international version should be more common.

Am I doing something wrong, or is TWRP not available for the GT-N7000?
If so, what should I use instead?

Comment: See the resources mentioned here: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/17153)

Comment: Looks like TWRP is not available for your device (7000 is not same a 7000B), trying to install TWRP could lead to serious issues. Cursory search on XDA shows other recoveries available. Not quoting them, since this is an old device and am not sure if support is ongoing. Please research yourself

Comment: i tried to install cwm on my gtn7000 and no luck it reboots to stock android

Comment: you should maybe create your own twrp image. Links: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/guide-porting-twrp-source-t3843473, https://www.xda-developers.com/compile-twrp-for-your-device/

Answer (score 1):

PhilZ Recovery is a CWM-based recovery with touch support.
I used that one. It even has signed zips, so you can flash it from stock recovery.

Answer (score 1):

On the TWRP website itself, it says that **TWRP cannot support the N7000**, because it does not have a separately bootable partition. I just found that statement after struggling and failing for an eternity to flash TWRP on my old N7000. The flashing itself always finishes without error, but afterwards the device still boots into the same old stock recovery. Apparently, it simply cannot work. ☹️

> The Samsung Galaxy Note 1 n7000 model will NEVER receive official TWRP support. The n7000 does not have a separately bootable recovery partition. Instead, you are stuck with whatever recovery is included in your ROM or kernel or boot image. You may find TWRP included in some ROMs, kernels, or boot images, especially if you can find OmniROM for your device.

https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxynoten7000.html